# Selendroid is not working?

Tags: selendroid

http://selendroid.io/setup.html
Here is given an example of what I should get when I open localhost at port 4444.

But instead I get:

```
{"value":{"os":{"name":"Windows 7","arch":"x86","version":"6.1"},"build":   
{"browserName":"selendroid","version":"0.10.0"},"supportedDevices":[],"supportedApps":
[{"mainActivity":"io.selendroid.androiddriver.WebViewActivity","appId":"io.selendroid.androiddriver:0.10.0",
"basePackage":"io.selendroid.androiddriver"}]},"status":0}
```

A device is connected to the PC and it has no screenlock, but it is not detected.

*What's wrong?*

(I don't have exp with Selenium or Selendroid and trying to start now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your device, you need to switch ON the USB debugging which is under developer mode.

then type command on command promt: `adb devices`

it should display attached devices.